# automation tool for application accessed remotely

Tags: testing

I am using citrix to access a application remotely. I am not able to use winrunner as it dosent identify objects as application is not installed on working PC. Is there any tool to automate such application

Answer (score 0):

Citrix has a product called [EdgeSight](http://www.citrix.com/english/ps2/products/product.asp?contentID=25119).  [Tevron](http://www.tevron.com) has a product called CitraTest.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml)?  It has a built-in recorder to record your keystrokes and mouse movements/clicks, which you can then dump into a script and playback.  You can also reference certain windows that present and preform special actions against such as hiding them or, adding/removing controls...really just about anything you want. They also have a great community forum see [here](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/index.php?)

Answer (score 0):

Is tevron Citrab Test tool is an open source tool?

Answer (score 0):

Citratest will work for what you are describing, but it is **not** open source.